# Xamarin Forms Rg.Plugins.Popup

Tags: c#, xamarin, popup

I'm trying to make a popup page in Xamarin Forms 3.0.0.530893. I use the Rg.Plugins.Popup v.1.1.4.158-pre and test it on Android 8.0.0. But the popup is displayed in the left top corner, no matter what I put in the Horizontal and Vertical options.

**Here is my Popup Page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ScanApp.Page.Popup.SignOutPopup"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Label Text="Log ud" TextColor="Black"></Label>
    <Label Text="AutomationProperties du sikker på du ønsker at logge ud?"></Label>
    <Button Text="LOG UD"></Button>
    <Button Text="ANNULLER"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

**And here is backend**

```
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ScanApp.Page.Popup
{
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class SignOutPopup : PopupPage
  {
    public SignOutPopup ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}
```

**Here I initialize the plugin for Android in MainActivity OnCreate**

```
 Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this,bundle);
```

**Here I push the page**

```
Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new SignOutPopup());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on how works this plugin exactly , but I already used it in a past project and here what I did:

I suggest you to define your page like this. Embed your stacklayout into a 'fullscreen' Frame, and set some margin and paddig to your frame:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ScanApp.Page.Popup.SignOutPopup"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         >

    <Frame HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" 
           BackgroundColor="White" Margin="20" Padding="20">

      <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Log ud" TextColor="Black"></Label>
        <Label Text="AutomationProperties du sikker på du ønsker at logge ud?"></Label>
        <Button Text="LOG UD"></Button>
        <Button Text="ANNULLER"></Button>
      </StackLayout>

    </Frame>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Xamarin Forms **Frame class** has specific properties like '**CornerRadius**' or '**HasShadow**' to give a real 'popup' appearance to your Frame... And your frame should be centered.

Tell me if it's working...

Comment: The problem still persist. I have been able to get it to center by setting a margin the same size as the picture i'm having on the page where the popup has been opened from.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the plugin or popup page. The problem was these lines that I put in the android MainActivity, for the app to fill the whole screen

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
   Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
   Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutInScreen);
   Window.DecorView.SetFitsSystemWindows(true);
}
```